# How to test a Laravel package that handles Eloquent models?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, eloquent, mocking

I've created a package that manipulates eloquent models, and I've created test cases for it.

The package is supposed to call `save()` or `delete()` for the models, at some point, which would attempt to hit the database.

#### Actual Database approach

As first attempt [I tried this approach](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-test-package-that-relies-on-eloquent-mock-db) and [also this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/guides/guide-how-to-run-integration-tests-from-a-package). The point is that in the context of a package (even using `orchestra/testbench`) I'd need to configure a database and migrations. Since the package itself does not have any model (but I've created a *dummy model* for test purposes) I see this approach as possibly overkill. In any case, I'd still accept to setup a prepared sqlite db in memory, which I also tried but could not make it work (It was attempting to use `forge` connection instead `sqlite` and I could not make it access another connection. I may provide details on what I did for it).

#### Mocking approach

Another possible attempt (as per my limited understanding on this) is to partially mock the model. But after I mocked it, it would not know how to handle other calls such as `fill()`, for which I was willing the common behavior, but I received a method not found exception.

#### Method override approach

Given that these two possible attempts went bad, I defaulted to a third possible approach which worked for me, but I'm honestly not sure if this is the way to go about it.

In order to avoid test failure due to lack of database when calling `save()` or `delete()` methods, I overrided them ([full source code here](https://github.com/alariva/laravel-modelmerge/blob/master/tests/DummyContact.php)) :

```
class DummyContact extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function save(array $options = [])
    {
        $this->exists = true;
        $this->wasRecentlyCreated = true;
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        $this->exists = false;
        $this->wasRecentlyCreated = false;
    }
}
```

This way, I'm able to test the following code ([full source here](https://github.com/alariva/laravel-modelmerge/blob/master/src/ModelMerge.php)):

```
public function unifyOnBase()
{
    $mergeModel = $this->merge();

    $this->modelA->fill($mergeModel->toArray());
    $this->modelA->save();
    $this->modelB->delete();

    return $this->modelA;
}
```

So my question is, is this approach acceptable? (I think it is fair, I don't see exceptional pitfalls, but I suspect there exist more elegant approaches). In case there are suggested approaches, like Mocking or using an actual DB for running the tests, I'd like to know [what adaptations should I do to my testing codebase](https://github.com/alariva/laravel-modelmerge/tree/master/tests) for taking them.

**Final but important note:** I'm not willing to test models itself, I'm willing to test my code that uses (and thus depends on models).

Comment: An integration test with an actual database is the most thorough way to test your code. IMO, you should at least have integration tests for the fundamental features. [This](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep/blob/master/tests/TestCase.php) is how I use an SQLite database for the tests of my package.

Comment: Thats sort of what id like to get working.ill try to pair your approach and post results.thanks for the ref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to comment of Jonas Staudenmeir:

> *An integration test with an actual database is the most thorough way to test your code. IMO, you should at least have integration tests for the fundamental features. [This is how](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep/blob/master/tests/TestCase.php) I use an SQLite database for the tests of my package.*

I could pair and get working the **in-memory sqlite** approach.

1. [Removed override functions](https://github.com/alariva/laravel-modelmerge/commit/1a86eed31be1766e89fe24ae5fe25cd47163568c#diff-147e1dc464029d9a1e7d7719307ef4f6L18)
2. [Added Capsule test case setUp code](https://github.com/alariva/laravel-modelmerge/commit/1a86eed31be1766e89fe24ae5fe25cd47163568c#diff-1cd3cb6e9b1662276b34c15da785af46R13) as per [this working project as example](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep/blob/master/tests/TestCase.php) (*Thanks for that*)
3. In my case I also required to install the sqlite driver `sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite`

[Tests now still run successfully](https://travis-ci.org/alariva/laravel-modelmerge/jobs/429009447), while the solution looks more elegant and cleans-up the function override workarounds which would easily break upon API upgrades of Eloquent Models. This would also enable easier access to testing relationship-dependent features of the package.

[image: Test pass]

Answer (score 2):

I think your first proposal, the *actual database approach* is the best - using the package [orchestra/testbench](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench).

Since you have no Eloquent models in your package, but your package modifies Eloquent models, I think you should create an Eloquent model only for testing purposes inside your test folder.

For example, put the `DummyContact` into `tests/Models/DummyContact.php` and put the migration file into `tests/Database/Migration/DummyContactMigration.php`.

Now all you need to do, is to setup a basic `TestCase.php`. 
Make sure to explicitly call the migration file of your `DummyContact` model.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyPackage\Tests;

use MyVendor\MyPackage\MyServiceProvider;

class TestCase extends \Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/database/migrations');
        $this->artisan('migrate', ['--database' => 'testbench'])->run();

    }

    /**
     * add the package provider
     *
     * @param $app
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getPackageProviders($app)
    {
        return [MyServiceProvider::class];
    }

    /**
     * Define environment setup.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Foundation\Application  $app
     * @return void
     */
    protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
    {
        // Setup default database to use sqlite :memory:
        $app['config']->set('database.default', 'testbench');
        $app['config']->set('database.connections.testbench', [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ]);
    }
}
```

You may also want to read this [blog post](https://medium.com/@iwasherefirst2/how-to-test-eloquent-models-in-a-laravel-package-3dbf30b44a19)